# Counting variable name, which will get appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have some trouble with my web project.
I'm looking for a solution how I can count my variable upwards in a loop.
So that the name of the variable will go like this: panel1, panel2, panel3...

**Thats my code**

```
var panel = []
for(i=1; i<3; i++){
var $div = $('<div class="panel3" id="panel3">Box2 - 20</div>');
$('.panel[i]').append($div);
}
```

so the "panel[i]" at the bottom should get a higher number for every loop. 
I was looking a long time for a solution, but nothing worked.

The idea behind my code is to fill all those empty boxes with a div.
[image: Idea behind code]

**Some HTML**

```
  <div class="panel-body">
  <!-- Reihe 1 -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="panel1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <div class="panel2">
          </div>
        </div>
```

And so on...

Thanks for the help

Comment: try with prepend

Comment: @REDEVI_ Thanks, but still doesn't work...

Comment: can you pls show some html?

Comment: @RaJeshRiJo Sure, hope this is enough. It's just the HTML part which will get interacted with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your panel name will be panel1, panel2, panel3, so on then you cannot do with this `$('.panel[i]')`. Instead of that do something like,

```
for(i=1; i<3; i++){
  var div = $('<div class="panel3">Box2 - 20</div>');
  var panelClass = '.panel'+i;
  $(panelClass).append(div);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Works fine.

Comment: So 3 elements having same Id in the end ? Hmmm.

Comment: Not suppose to. Updated, I just try to explain how to append loop variable with class. so didn't noticed.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Sure, you're right. Forgot about that. I will implement some parts of your solution. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is String concatenation with the value of `i`

```
var $div = $('<div class="panel3" id="panel'+i+'">Box2 - 20</div>');
```

And also in the below you doesn't need an array. Just use the parent container identity

```
$(parentSelector).append($div);
```

In case if you need all the html in an array

```
panel[i] = $div;
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I realized how ***** the names are I gave. The class = panel3 and id = panel3 shouldn't change. Just the panel[i] at the bottom.

Comment: @CallMeLeonardo No I guess. You can keep the class name but ID should be Unique. If you leave it as is , you end up having many elements having same Id. If you want to keep them same, keep your code as is.

Comment: Well, didn't realize my mistake. Of course you're right. I will implement this part from your solution. Thanks